# На срабатывает событие CellContentClick на первый столбец

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

Столкнулся с тем, что при клике по ячейке ожидаю вывод в MessageBox содержимого ячейки, но это срабатывает только для столбцов 1 и далее(не для 0-го). Но при нажатии на заголовок столбца - выводится содержимое выделенной ячейки. Скриншот илюстрирует. 
При нажатии на ячейку с G20(синий круг) - ничего не происходит. Но если потом нажать на "Название..."(красный круг) Появится окно со значением. 
Если нажать на любую из 2-х дат - выведется дата. И если потом нажать, пока выделена ячейка, на любой заголовок - выведется выделенная дата. 
Я никак не могу понять почему. Предполагаю, что дело в наполнении таблицы. Я гружу данные из SQLite таблицы вот таким кодом:

```
private void IndexerList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
DataSet StaleData = new DataSet();
string query =  "Select hostname as 'Хост', indexName as 'Название индекса', indexDate as 'Дата сборки' From stales"; 
string ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + baseName; 
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString); SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, connection);
dataAdapter.Fill(StaleData);
grid_table.DataSource = StaleData.Tables[0].DefaultView;
connection.Close();
}
```

Это происходит, когда я скролю значения в ComboBox, в будущем будет сортировка через Where, где в зависимости от содержимого ComboBox, будет выводится только нужная часть.

Сама DataGridView(grid_table) пустая, т.е. не заведено ни одного столбца, столбцы создаются и размечаются в момент импорта из DataSet.

Вызов окна по клику происходит так:

```
private void O4dbase_CellContentClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
var info = grid_table.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(info);
}
```

[image: Результат нажатия на заголовок]

Подскажите, где я что-то делаю не так?

Не знаю, как правильно отвечать самому себе, но отмечу здесь, вдруг кто столкнутся. Ответа почему так происходит я не нашёл, но изменил:

grid_table.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.grid_table_CellClick);

на

grid_table.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.grid_table_CellContentClick);

Так при клике по ячейке отрабатывает.

Comment: А что такое `O4dbase`? Это тот-же самый `grid_table` или другой компонент?

Comment: Вообще, используйте свойства `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` - `e.ColumnIndex` и `e.RowIndex`.

Comment: Да, это незаконченные правки. 04base = grid_table. А зачем мне получать индексы ячеек? В любом случае, это не помогает вызвать событие click при нажатии на ячейки первого столбца.